# iOS Charts centering x- and y-axis

Tags: ios, swift, charts

For plotting graphs I use the Charts framework from this site https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts. I want to know if it possible to center the x- and y-axis to look like this:

[image]

I tried to move the x-Axis and the left-Axis to center, but it only moves the label values but not the axes, as you can see in the below picture
[image]

Here is an example of my code:

```
var lineChartView: LineChartView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    lineChartView = LineChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    lineChartView?.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(lineChartView!)
    
    let ys1 = Array(0..<100).map { x in ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x) / 10, y: sin(Double(x) / 10)) }
    let ys2 = Array(0..<100).map { x in ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x) / 10, y: cos(Double(x) / 10)) }
    
    let data = LineChartData()
    let ds1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: ys1, label: "sine")
    ds1.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
    ds1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    ds1.drawValuesEnabled = false
    ds1.mode = .cubicBezier
    data.addDataSet(ds1)
    
    let ds2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: ys2, label: "cosine")
    ds2.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
    ds2.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    ds2.drawValuesEnabled = false
    ds2.mode = .cubicBezier
    data.addDataSet(ds2)
    self.lineChartView.data = data
    lineChartView.xAxis.enabled = true
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChartView.xAxis.yOffset = -self.view.frame.height/2
    
    lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    
    // left axis
    lineChartView.leftAxis.xOffset = -self.view.frame.width/2
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code, you might need to set chart.setVisibleRange too

```
chart.xAxis.granularity = 1
chart.leftAxis.granularity = 1
chart.leftAxis.axisMaximum = maxYValue
chart.xAxis.axisMaximum = maxXValue
chart.xAxis.axisMinimum = -maxXValue
chart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = -maxYValue
```

Comment: Still, only the values of the axes are moved but not the axes themselves.